# How to simplifying this R Code to detect repeated sequence

Tags: r

I found this below function to detect repeated sequence. I integrate the function into Monte Carlo Simulation to calculate the probability. The function I have is too long and takes too much time during the simulation. I would appreciate if anyone can help to simply the function and in turn fasten any simulation depends on it.

```
V1 <- c(68,71,72,69,80,78,80,81,84,82,67,73,65,68,66,70,69,72,74,73,68,75,70,72,75,73,69,75,74,79,80,78,80,81,79,82,69,73,67,66,70,72,69,72,75,80,68,69,71,77,70,73)

Check_repeat_Seq <- function(vector){
  k <- 2:25
  Lall <- setNames(lapply(k, function(i) table(zoo::rollapply(vector, width = i, toString))), k)
  
  L <- Filter(length, lapply(Lall, function(x) x[x == max(x) & x > 1]))

dat <- data.frame(seq_rep=sapply(L, length))

dat$repeat_length <- as.numeric(rownames(dat))

return(max(dat$repeat_length))

}

Check_repeat_Seq(V1)

#### Can you please simplify the following also to calculate the sum of repeated.####

Check_repeat_Seq_no_overlap_sum <- function(vector){
  k <- 2:25
  Lall <- setNames(lapply(k, function(i) table(zoo::rollapply(vector, width = i, toString))), k)
  
  L <- Filter(length, lapply(Lall, function(x) x[x == max(x) & x > 1]))
  vec <- unlist(unname(L))
  nms <- names(vec)
  is_le <- function(i) any(grepl(nms[i], tail(nms, -i)) & (vec[i] <= tail(vec, -i)))
  LL <- vec[ ! sapply(seq_along(nms), is_le) ]
  dat <- data.frame(seq_rep=sapply(L, length))
  dat$repeat_length <- as.numeric(rownames(dat))
  dat$total_repeat <- dat$seq_rep*dat$repeat_length
  
  return(sum(dat$total_repeat))
}

##### the original function should return data Frame as follows 

Check_All_repeat_Seq<- function(vector){
  k <- 2:25
  Lall <- setNames(lapply(k, function(i) table(zoo::rollapply(vector, width = i, toString))), k)
  
  L <- Filter(length, lapply(Lall, function(x) x[x == max(x) & x > 1]))
  vec <- unlist(unname(L))
  nms <- names(vec)
  is_le <- function(i) any(grepl(nms[i], tail(nms, -i)) & (vec[i] <= tail(vec, -i)))
  LL <- vec[ ! sapply(seq_along(nms), is_le) ]
  dat <- data.frame(seq_rep=sapply(L, length))
  dat$repeat_length <- as.numeric(rownames(dat))
  dat$total_repeat <- dat$seq_rep*dat$repeat_length
  
  return(sum(dat))
}
```

please help simplifying the code with the same output

Comment: I'm not sure you're going to be able to speed it up much, to be honest, though I hope I'm wrong. I suggest that if you're at this stage of code-optimization, you may want to become familiar with the `profvis` package that will show where the majority of the time is being spent, expression-by-expression. In this case, the (vast) majority of time is spent within `rollapply`, which makes sense to me. If you're really out to speed it up, simplify your problem to *just that part*, and see if you can mimic its effect with other code tricks. Good luck!

Comment: Currently it considers 'aaa' as having two instances of 'aa'.  If it would be sufficient to exclude overlaps so that there is only one occurrence of 'aa' in that example then that would reduce the number of subsequences that have to be considered.  Also it could be rewritten in C++.

Comment: following ideas of subsequences, maybe longest subsequence problem, Rabin hashing, or  KMP algorithm are what you are looking for. (I didn't actually run to see what output you desire)

Comment: Can you explain what the two additional functions (`Check_repeat_Seq_no_overlap_sum` and `Check_All_repeat_Seq`) are supposed to do?

Comment: See update 2 in my answer to get your `dat` `data.frame`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the very helpful code. You are a great R programmer. Can it be modified to ignore the subsequent repeats? for example, if three numbers are found under two different sequences how this can be avoided

Comment: for this function "Check_All_repeat_Seq", it calculate the repeated sequences but try to ignore the overlap and return all repeats in array. But array can not be integrated in Monte Carlo Simulation using parametric bootstrap to compare this repeated sequence against the expected repeated sequence generated by pseudo-population from resampling.

Comment: The "Check repeat Seq no overlap sum" function computes the sum of repeated sequences. For instance, if the values 25 and 27 are repeated three times, and the values 33, 44, 34 are repeated three times, and so on. It adds a repeated sequence of 25 and 27 as 2 repeated 3 times for a total of 2*3 plus a repeated sequence of 33, 44, 34 for a total of 3*3. The result should be a single number between 2*3 and 3*3=15. The function is then integrated in a resampling with replacement function to calculate the probability that this repeat conforms to random sampling.

Comment: Would you like me to share the random sampling code to help to optimize the whole code?

Comment: I don't know if I'm fully following the additional programming problems you're having. It sounds like you got a good solution to the original problem you posted along with a problem you tacked on later. Instead of turning this question into a running problem, it's probably time to start the process over: research solutions to your new problem and then ask a new question specific to the new problem, including showing what you've tried and expected input/output. That way, you'll be able to get fresh eyes on it. You can add a comment here with a link to the new question.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have taken your advice and post the new question in separate post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70904837/adapting-and-optimizing-r-code-to-calculate-repeated-sequence)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

An even faster iterative approach leveraging the [Cantor pairing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function):

```
allDup <- function(x) {
  duplicated(x) | duplicated(x, fromLast = TRUE)
}

fPair <- function(i, j) {
  # Cantor pairing function
  k <- j + (i + j)*(i + j + 1L)/2L
  match(k, unique(k))
}

Check_repeat_Seq3 <- function(v) {
  v <- match(v, unique(v))
  vPair <- fPair(head(v, -1), tail(v, -1))
  blnKeep <- allDup(vPair)
  idx <- which(blnKeep)
  len <- 1L
  
  while (length(idx)) {
    len <- len + 1L
    vPair <- fPair(vPair[blnKeep], v[idx + len])
    blnKeep <- allDup(vPair)
    idx <- idx[blnKeep]
  }
  
  return(len)
}

# benchmark against the rollaply solution

V1 <- c(68,71,72,69,80,78,80,81,84,82,67,73,65,68,66,70,69,72,74,73,68,75,70,72,75,73,69,75,74,79,80,78,80,81,79,82,69,73,67,66,70,72,69,72,75,80,68,69,71,77,70,73)

Check_repeat_Seq <- function(vector){
  k <- 2:25
  Lall <- setNames(lapply(k, function(i) table(zoo::rollapply(vector, width = i, toString))), k)
  L <- Filter(length, lapply(Lall, function(x) x[x == max(x) & x > 1]))
  dat <- data.frame(seq_rep=sapply(L, length))
  dat$repeat_length <- as.numeric(rownames(dat))
  return(max(dat$repeat_length))
}

Check_repeat_Seq(V1)
#> [1] 4
Check_repeat_Seq3(V1)
#> [1] 4

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(Check_repeat_Seq(V1), Check_repeat_Seq3(V1))
#> Unit: microseconds
#>                   expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq     max neval
#>   Check_repeat_Seq(V1) 38445.7 40860.95 43153.058 42249.25 44051.15 60593.2   100
#>  Check_repeat_Seq3(V1)   103.9   118.65   150.713   149.05   160.05   465.2   100
```

**Original Solution**

```
Check_repeat_Seq2 <- function(v) {
  m <- matrix(c(head(v, -1), tail(v, -1)), ncol = 2)
  idx <- which(duplicated(m) | duplicated(m, fromLast = TRUE))
  len <- 2L
  
  while (length(idx)) {
    len <- len + 1L
    m <- matrix(v[sequence(rep(len, length(idx)), idx)], ncol = len, byrow = TRUE)
    idx <- idx[duplicated(m) | duplicated(m, fromLast = TRUE)]
  }
  
  return(len - 1L)
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

This should return your `dat` `data.frame`:

```
Check_repeat_Seq3 <- function(v) {
  v1 <- match(v, unique(v))
  vPair <- fPair(head(v1, -1), tail(v1, -1))
  blnKeep <- allDup(vPair)
  idx <- which(blnKeep)
  
  if (length(idx)) {
    len <- 1L
    seq_rep <- integer(length(v)/2)
    
    while (length(idx)) {
      len <- len + 1L
      vPair <- fPair(vPair[blnKeep], v1[idx + len])
      blnKeep <- allDup(vPair)
      seq_rep[len] <- nrow(unique(matrix(v[sequence(rep(len, length(blnKeep)), idx)], ncol = len, byrow = TRUE)))
      idx <- idx[blnKeep]
    }
    
    len <- 2:len
    return(data.frame(seq_rep = seq_rep[len], repeat_length = len, total_repeat = seq_rep[len]*len))
  } else {
    return(data.frame(seq_rep = integer(0), repeat_length = integer(0), total_repeat = integer(0)))
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. The code you provided make life easy. Do you have a similar way to calculate the sum of different repeats using a similar iterative way?

Comment: Two functions are added to the original post for your help to simplify

Comment: Thank you so much for the very helpful code. You are a great R programmer. Can it be modified to ignore the subsequent repeats? for example, if three numbers are found under two different sequences how this can be avoided.